# Разница между Chronometer и CountDownTimer

Tags: java, android, мобильная-разработка, app

Создаю приложение, которое каждый день даёт задания. Задание даётся раз в 24 часа. По окончании таймера появляется кнопка. Что в данном случае лучше использовать: Chronometer с setBaseCountDown или CountDownTimer? Какая разница между ними? И возможно ли реализовать действие по окончанию обратного отсчёта через Chronometer?

Comment: что такое "каждый день даёт задания"? "По окончании таймера появляется кнопка" - У вас уже есть какой то таймер?

Comment: Имелось в виду "будет давать задание"

Comment: Можете описать, как это технически выглядеть должно?

Comment: Alarm Manager без вариантов